# Input/Output error in ubuntu but can read data from windows

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I have a dual boot laptop with windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu was installed and working fine, untill suddenly it stopped booting up

It gets an Input/Output error while reading /dev/sda6.

On the other hand, the windows boot normally and I can even access data on my linux partition /dev/sda6 using a third party program DiskInternals.

I have tried reinstalling linux with an Ubuntu 18.04 live USB but it fails with the error message "error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda input/output error"

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: -->
[Screenshot of Disks App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNxv9.png)

Output of `grep -i sda6 /var/log/syslog*`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ grep -i sda6 /var/log/syslog
Jun 25 01:42:08 ubuntu lvm[1097]:   /dev/sda6: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 220201943040: Input/output error
Jun 25 01:42:08 ubuntu lvm[1097]:   /dev/sda6: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 220202000384: Input/output error
Jun 25 01:42:08 ubuntu lvm[1097]:   /dev/sda6: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
Jun 25 01:42:08 ubuntu lvm[1097]:   /dev/sda6: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
Jun 25 01:42:08 ubuntu kernel: [    7.481627]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8
Jun 25 01:42:08 ubuntu kernel: [   10.124131] EXT4-fs (sda6): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
Jun 25 01:42:08 ubuntu kernel: [   10.124133] EXT4-fs (sda6): write access will be enabled during recovery
Jun 25 01:42:08 ubuntu kernel: [  147.204149] EXT4-fs (sda6): error loading journal
Jun 25 01:42:10 ubuntu kernel: [  158.444325] Buffer I/O error on dev sda6, logical block 53760240, async page read
Jun 25 01:42:39 ubuntu kernel: [  186.822855] Buffer I/O error on dev sda6, logical block 53760240, async page read
```

Output of `fsck /dev/sda6`

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda6

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me the `Disks` app SMART Data window. Also show me `grep -i sda6 /var/log/syslog*`. If this log is too large, use paste.ubuntu.com and give me the link. Do you know how to fsck /dev/sda6?

Comment: I have updated the post. Please check

Comment: Thank you for your info. However, we didn't get the right info. Once you start the `Disks` app, go to the "hamburger" icon at the top right, and choose `SMART Data & Tests`. I need to see a screenshot of the SMART Data window. I've written a brief answer showing you how to properly fsck. Also show me `grep -i sda6 /var/log/syslog*` and if that output is large, use paste.ubuntu.com, or if it's small, just edit it into your question. Is sda6 a HDD or SSD?

Comment: `SMART Data and Tests` is not highlighted and thus I cannot click it. See https://imgur.com/a/4OyhPFC
I have added the output of grep to the question. The disk sda is a 2TB HDD on my laptop, and sda6 is the ext4 partition on which linux is installed.

Answer (score 1):

> On the other hand, the windows boot normally and I can even access data on my linux partition /dev/sda6 using a third party program DiskInternals.

This is the root of your Problem. Since ubuntu bionic `e2fsprogs`
 creates filesystem with new feature. `Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum`
 I mean metadata_csum.

copied from man e2fsck

> This ext4 feature enables metadata checksumming.  This feature
>                 stores checksums for all of the filesystem metadata
>                 (superblock, group descriptor blocks, inode and block bitmaps,
>                 directories, and extent tree blocks).  The checksum algorithm
>                 used for the metadata blocks is different than the one used
>                 for group descriptors with the uninit_bg feature.  These two
>                 features are incompatible and metadata_csum will be used
>                 preferentially instead of uninit_bg.

During access with your windows programm it changes/corrupts this stored metadata.

Comment: +1 good catch. The info about accessing the Linux partition from Windows came a little later than I could prove.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets first check your file system for errors.**

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Well, this was one very strange HDD problem.

Bottom line... From Windows, we deleted the Ubuntu sda6 partition, removed the Ubuntu boot record from the BIOS, booted to a Ubuntu Live USB, reinstalled Ubuntu, and restored data. It all works again!

Comment: I already tried it. But fdisk does not recognize /dev/sda (which is my internal HDD). See https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xgBZ5QpGxP/ 
Also fsck fails with:
```
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda6

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: @aman I think you're using LVM. You may have to use `sudo fsck -f /` or `sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper--vg-root` (or something similar. Look at `df` for the correct device name).

Comment: No, I am presently using an ubuntu 18.04 live USB.

Comment: @aman Of course! Duh! Sorry about that. It's called a senior moment :-) Both images you posted show that every partition is an unknown file system. Windows drivers that allow users to read/write to Linux partitions always corrupt the disk, and I'm wondering if DiskInternals has the same problem. Are you using LVM? Show me the `df` command.

Comment: Here is the output of the `df` command --> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/54xqdmyfKF/
Also, the problem started before installing Diskinternals

Comment: This doesn't look good. While booted to the Ubuntu Live USB, try `sudo e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda6`.

Comment: I get the following error:
`
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda6
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
e2fsck: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda6

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95356/discussion-between-aman-and-heynnema).

Comment: I have already taken a backup of all of my data in the linux partition. I still cannot understand, why can I normally boot into windows and even access the data on the HDD in the linux partition, but a live USB of ubuntu cannot identify or mount any of the partitions. Do you have any clue regarding it?